# performance of rho2hat and ppm in spatstat

Tags: ppm, spatstat

I want to compare the performance of nonparametric intensity function estimator "rho2hat" with "ppm".

My question how can I perform a test to see estimation works better? I couldn't use quadrat.test?

Comment: Please add some reproducible code including your data (or fake example data with the same structure) and how you used `rho2hat` and `ppm` and explain what you mean by the "estimation works better".

Comment: In below code I try to analyse "bei" dataset by ppm and rho2hat:      library(spatstat)
library(dismo)
data(bei)
bei
attach(bei.extra)
#plot()
non<-rho2hat(bei, elev, grad)
fit <- ppm(bei, ~elev+grad, covariates=bei.extra)

# plot of estimated intensity function at all locations

pred<- predict(non)
plot(pred)
plot(bei, add=TRUE)

Comment: Now one method should be dividing the window to grids and compare the expected frequencies for two methods of ppm and rho2hat. How can I write the code?

Comment: This will not evaluate which method has better performance (whatever that means). It will just measure the difference between the two results.

Comment: FYI: There is a bug in `predict.rho2hat` in the current released version of spatstat (1.51-0), so please install the development version from GitHub if you intend to use it (any version after 1.51-0.033 should be OK).

Comment: Hi @AdrianBaddeley I'm wondering what approach you recommend to compare performances of IPP with Nonparametric intensity function estimation?

Comment: Hi @EgeRubak thanks for your comments. I also installed the development version from GitHub but I got an error! my code as below:            
 data(bei)
bei
attach(bei.extra)
#
non<-rho2hat(bei, elev, grad)       M1<-quadrat.test(non, nx=4,ny=2)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment by @adrian-baddeley your suggested strategy
will just measure the difference between two results. The way you can
calculate the expected number of points in different regions from an
estimated intensity is as follows:

```r
library(spatstat)
#> Loading required package: nlme
#> Loading required package: rpart
#> 
#> spatstat 1.51-0.035       (nickname: 'Spatfefe') 
#> For an introduction to spatstat, type 'beginner'
elev <- bei.extra$elev
grad <- bei.extra$grad
non <- rho2hat(bei, elev, grad)
pred <- predict(non)
grid <- quadrats(pred, nx = 4, ny = 2)
by(pred, grid, integral)
#> 1:
#> [1] 522.0247
#> 
#> 2:
#> [1] 503.6255
#> 
#> 3:
#> [1] 344.8552
#> 
#> 4:
#> [1] 522.834
#> 
#> 5:
#> [1] 454.5958
#> 
#> 6:
#> [1] 470.2484
#> 
#> 7:
#> [1] 556.1989
#> 
#> 8:
#> [1] 415.8889
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Ege-Rubak, I have no access to spatstat 1.51-0.035! so my results of running your code is quite different from your. However, My expertise is nonparametric statistics and I have some ideas for improving the performance of "rhohat"/ "rho2hat" by imposing some constraints. Regards Hassan Doosti